# Display Product category in archive product page

Tags: categories

I want to display the category products in the store page ie archive-product.php. But early it was working, when i add new category it was not display the category product and the url is going correct but it goes to home page of that site. Can u pls help me whats is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you made any modifications to your code, you might want to flush your permalinks.  Go to Settings -> Permalinks, this will flush them.  Then head back to your archives page.

If this doesn't help, show us some code please.

Comment: Hi MrJustin, can you pls tel me how to flush...?

Comment: Yeah, login to wp-admin.  Go to settings, then go to permalinks.  This will flush them, then view your page(s).

Comment: ya, i did it, but no change

Comment: Then your going to have to edit your question and include some code.  That will give us a better idea of what your doing at the moment, and we can help you from there.

Comment: That's not code, that's a website.  I can't grab raw files from there.